# Raplacing for loop by a single line statement in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have this function which needs to be run hundreds of times. It contains a `for` loop which I am trying to remove to make the function faster. Can someone help me replace the loop by a single line command.

```
nn = 4;
T = [5 1 2; 5 2 3; 5 3 4; 5 4 1];
p = [0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1; 0.5 0.5];
A = zeros(nn,1);    
for i=1:nn
    sctr = T(i,:); pT = p(sctr,:);
    A(i) = 1/2*det([pT,ones(3,1)]);  
end
```

Perhaps removing `det` and replacing it with actual formula to calculate the determinant will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The For loop solution you have is probably the fastest. Other options are:

```
B = [p(T',:),ones(3*size(T,1),1)] 
C= mat2cell(B,[3,3,3,3],3)
D= cellfun(@det,C);
```

or also you can write instead of `D` this expression

```
D = arrayfun(@(x) det(C{x}), 1 : size(C, 1));
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work (I couldn't test it since I don't have my environment with me)

```
pT = p(T(1:nn,:),:);
A = 1/2 * det([pT, ones(3, 1)]);
```

You can obviously do a one line code from the code above but this would be less readable.

If it doesn't work and you keep the for-loop, at least consider the matrix preallocation (for A, pT and sctr) this will speed up your program.

Comment: this wouldn't work because the combined matrix dimensions are not consistent.